# Site showing lots of Ð ÑƒÑÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹] Characters

Tags: html

I have this joomla site. I have two versions of it, both using the same database. One has these characters allover the text. The other seems to be alright. What could be the problem? My database is the same so I don't believe it is a character set issue on the db. Anyone?

Comment: Could you add links to the websites in question?

Comment: is the encoding correct both in the doctype and the http header?

Comment: What would be the correct encoding codeinchaos?

Comment: The correct encoding would be whatever encoding the data is that you're sending to the client. You should probably be sending utf-8, but if that's not what you're sending, that shouldn't be in the headers.

Comment: My db is set to utf8. The funny thing is that am using the same struct on 2 sites using the same db, one is showing correctly while the other has all these characters!!

Comment: Couldn't get it to work as I wanted to I jst connected to the files from the working version so am basically running one instance of joomla on 2 domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with the encoding. You're not saying where you get this, so my guess is that it's the browser. Try to change the page encoding (check the menus of your browser) to `UTF-8` (or "Unicode"). That should fix it.

If that works, check the code and make sure pages are sent with [correct `charset` settings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset).

Another source of these problems is that the code reads UTF-8 data from the database as bytes and then encodes that again as UTF-8.